# Showing wrong data when filtered RecyclerView item is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, search, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with search bar in my android app. When I search in it and click on an item, it shows wrong data.

I know why it happens but I don't know how to fix it. I have tried many things but still I have the problem.

Here is the code of my Adapter.

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<hisAdapter.hisViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<hisItem> mhislist;
    public onItemClickListener mListener;

    public  interface onItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void  setOnitemClickLIstener(onItemClickListener lIstener) {
        mListener = lIstener;
    }

    public class hisViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;
        public TextView card_num;

        public hisViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            card_num = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   if (mListener != null) {
                       int position = getAdapterPosition();
                       if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                           mListener.onItemClick(position);
                       }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public hisAdapter(ArrayList<hisItem> hisList){
         mhislist = hisList;
    }

    @Override
    public hisViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View v = 
      LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.his_item, parent, false);
      hisViewHolder hvh = new hisViewHolder(v);

      return hvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(hisViewHolder holder, int position) {
        hisItem currentItem = mhislist.get(position);
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
        holder.card_num.setText(currentItem.getText3());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mhislist.size();
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<hisItem> filteredList){
        mhislist = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the `MainActivity` where I have a search functionality code and click handler.

```
editTextt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            filter(editable.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void filter(String text) {
    ArrayList<hisItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (hisItem item : hisList) {
        if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }

    mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, singleActivity.class);
    hisItem clickeditem = hisList.get(position);
    String pos = String.valueOf(position);
    intent.putExtra(CARD_NUM ,pos );
    intent.putExtra(HEAD_LINE,clickeditem.getText1());
    intent.putExtra(REAL_NUM,clickeditem.getText3());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Please let me know if there's anything I need to add in my question. I am available to provide those. Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code properly in your question. DO NOT USE RANDOM formatting. The eyes really hurt when I see some questions like this.

Comment: okay . but do you know solution ?

Comment: I cannot look into the question properly if the code and the question is not properly formatted. The question is hard to read.

Comment: what is wrong formated exactly? and how to edit it ?

Comment: Okay. Let me edit your code.

Comment: Please check now. You are welcome :)

Comment: okay,thanks.that was my first question . so do you know the solution?

Comment: I am writing an answer. Lets see if I can help you more. Stay tight.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the issue in two different ways. You might consider changing the function in your `MainActivity`. Because what you are doing in your `onItemClick` function is wrong. You are getting the item from the `hisList` when some items from this `hisList` are already filtered out. So you need to get the items from your `filteredList` in this case. This can be easily achieved by declaring the `filteredList` as a global variable in your `MainActivity`.

```
// Declaring the filteredList as a public variable that can be accessed from anywhere in this class.
public ArrayList<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, singleActivity.class);

    // Get the item from the filteredList which is the updated one.
    hisItem clickeditem = filteredList.get(position);

    String pos = String.valueOf(position);
    intent.putExtra(CARD_NUM ,pos );
    intent.putExtra(HEAD_LINE,clickeditem.getText1());
    intent.putExtra(REAL_NUM,clickeditem.getText3());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, the second way is to integrate the `onClick` behaviour in your adapter. I prefer this as this is simple and this is not prone to error. It will be always handling the list passed to the adapter. So there is no other headache.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, singleActivity.class);
        hisItem clickeditem = mhislist.get(position);
        String pos = String.valueOf(position);
        intent.putExtra("CARD_NUMBER", pos);
        intent.putExtra("HEAD_LINE", clickeditem.getText1());
        intent.putExtra("REAL_NUMBER", clickeditem.getText3());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i am trying to fix it in second way... but when i am writing intent arguments it is marked as wrong can you tell me why ?

Comment: Can you please check now? The variables were not found in your adapter I guess. Also keep in mind that you need to pass the context while you are initializing your adapter.

Comment: now "startActivity(intent)" is marked as bug .whats wrong with it ?

Comment: everything works fine but when i filter i got wrong position on click.is it possible to fix it ?

Comment: Great to know that it helped.

Comment: can you tell me how to access unfiltered list positions while list is filtered ? it sounds confusing but i hope you will get it

Comment: I did not get the question. Sorry. What do you mean by the position of unfiltered list. When the list is filtered, all positions are recalculated. If you want to maintain the position of the previous unfiltered list, then you just have to maintain a separate list which will contain original data all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will solve your problem definitely!!

```
private ArrayList<Employee> filteredList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    private void filter(String text) {
      filteredList.clear();
      for (Employee item : mEmployeeList) {
        if (item.getVehicle_number().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
          filteredList.add(item);
        }
      }
      myadapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
      Intent ediIntent = new Intent(this, Edit_Activity.class);
      if(filteredList.size() > 0) {
        Employee clickedItem = filteredList.get(position);
       } else {
          Employee clickedItem = mEmployeeList.get(position);
       }
      ...
    }
```